# Javascript let hoisting to the scope or creating where it is?

Tags: javascript, scope, let

x declared after fn function but returns its value.
Why fn didn't return undefined?

```js
function doWork(){

  let fn = function(){ return x; }
  let x = 2;

  return fn();

}

console.log(doWork()); // 2
```

Comment: Please read how scope works in js https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Because `fn()` is called *after* `x` is assigned.

Comment: `let` creates variables in a scope. There’s no ordering within a scope, just a "temporal dead zone". If this didn't work, it would be super annoying.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916940/why-was-the-name-let-chosen-for-block-scoped-variable-declarations-in-javascri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `doWork()` function, first you set up a function and assign it to `fn` --  This function is **not** invoked yet. You then define `x` as `2`. **After** this definition you invoke `fn()` by calling `return fn()`.

Because JavaScript works from top-to-bottom, `x` is defined at the time you reference `fn()`, so `fn()` is able to `return x` correctly.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function doWork() {
  let fn = function() {
    return x;
  }
  let x = 2;
  return fn();
}

console.log(doWork()); // 2
```